# Can Kombu do publish and sucscribe to multiple consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, kombu

Using Kombu with RabbitMQ to implement a classic publish/subscribe design pattern.  I have created a producer that creates a topic:

```
from kombu import Connection, Exchange, Queue

media_exchange = Exchange('media', 'topic', durable=False)
video_queue = Queue('video', exchange=media_exchange, routing_key='video')

with Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost//') as conn:
    producer = conn.Producer(serializer='json')
    producer.publish('Hello World!',
                      exchange=media_exchange, routing_key='video',
                      declare=[video_queue])
```

I then created a consumer to consume from the publisher:

```
from kombu import Connection, Exchange, Queue

media_exchange = Exchange('media', type='topic', durable=False)
video_queue = Queue('video', exchange=media_exchange, routing_key='video')

def process_media(body, message):
    print(body)
    #message.ack()

with Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost//') as conn:
    with conn.Consumer(video_queue, callbacks=[process_media]) as consumer:
        # Process messages and handle events on all channels
        while True:
            conn.drain_events()
```

In then launch two consumers, each one in a separate terminal; both wait for a message:

```
terminal 1: python consumer.py
terminal 2: python consumer.py
```

When I run the producer, only one consumer receives the message.

Answer (score 7):

The producer publishes in an exchange, not in a queue. The queues are defined by the consumers. When using different queue name for each consumer then all will get the message.
When using many consumers for the same queue then it is load balancing, that's why only one of your consumers gets the message.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify, the messages in the queue are 'consumed' i.e. the first consumer consumes it, and the message is no more in the queue, that's why the second consumer isn't getting anything.

To have 2 separate consumers for same message - use 2 separate queues i.e.
`video_queue1` and `video_queue2`, declared and bound to the exchange `media_exchange`, using same key `video`.

**producer.py**

```
from kombu import Connection, Exchange, Queue

media_exchange = Exchange('media', 'topic', durable=False)
video_queue1 = Queue('video1', exchange=media_exchange, routing_key='video')
video_queue2 = Queue('video2', exchange=media_exchange, routing_key='video')


with Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost//') as conn:
    producer = conn.Producer(serializer='json')
    producer.publish('Hello World!',
                      exchange=media_exchange, routing_key='video',
                      declare=[video_queue1, video_queue2])
```

**consumer1.py**

```
from kombu import Connection, Exchange, Queue

media_exchange = Exchange('media', type='topic', durable=False)
video_queue = Queue('video1', exchange=media_exchange, routing_key='video')

def process_media(body, message):
    print(body)
    #message.ack()

with Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost//') as conn:
    with conn.Consumer(video_queue, callbacks=[process_media]) as consumer:
        # Process messages and handle events on all channels
        while True:
            conn.drain_events()
```

**consumer2.py**

```
from kombu import Connection, Exchange, Queue

media_exchange = Exchange('media', type='topic', durable=False)
video_queue = Queue('video2', exchange=media_exchange, routing_key='video')

def process_media(body, message):
    print(body)
    #message.ack()

with Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost//') as conn:
    with conn.Consumer(video_queue, callbacks=[process_media]) as consumer:
        # Process messages and handle events on all channels
        while True:
            conn.drain_events()
```

Comment: If you declare the queues without specifying a name then the server will automatically generate a random name which does not conflict with an existing queue.

Comment: Will revive old question:
Based on RabbitMQ ability you have one more variant:
- Make exchange1-to-exchange2 binding - exchange1 is the same "topic" exchange "media_exchange";  bind is made by routing key "video"; exchange2 is type "fanout".
That way many consumers will receive message. And the producer will send only one message.